Mouse Mode in C++WinRT?
I am trying to enable mouse mode on the root Page element in a Blank App (C++/WinRT) project. I have an Xbox 1 controller attached to a Xbox 1 usb dongle. So far I have coded a small xaml file with a number of different controls. When I run it, the app recognizes the controller for XY Focus Navigation, mouse pointer input from my mouse, and keyboard input (when I press tab, control focus changes from one control to the next).
I have read all the msdn documents for Gamepad control (I think). I have tried implementing mouse mode using the statements provided at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/gamepad-and-remote-interactions#mouse-mode:
this->InitializeComponent();
this->RequiresPointerMode(winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::ApplicationRequiresPointerMode::WhenRequested);
Suspending({ this, &App::OnSuspending });

as well as adding the proper RequiresPointer property to the Page element in xaml:
RequiresPointer="WhenFocused"

I believe it is simply a matter of changing to mouse mode, but maybe I am wrong. Like I said at top, when the app runs, XY Focus Navigation works. I am hoping to be able to have the xbox controller's left thumbstick move the pointer in the same fashion that the mouse moves the pointer. Am I missing something else?

What is the discrepancy between the behaviour with the thumb-stick on the XBox, and that when testing with the mouse on the development PC? You state that your XAML application is correctly receiving mouse and keyboard input but it's less clear why you believe that "mouse mode" is not working working.

I was testing the UWP app on PC. In the MSDN documentation for RequiresPointer it says that it would be ignored unless the app is running on Xbox. I ran the app on Xbox and it works fine. This is good. However, I would still like to be able to use the Xbox controller in mouse mode for developing PC games in UWP C++/WinRT. Is this possible? I have looked through Pointer, UINavigation, and Gamepad topics, and I am left in the original position - I can't get the program to produce mouse mode navigation - only XY Focus Navigation.
